# looping program for MLP Keras prediction

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, regression, prediction

I am (sort of a beginner starting out) experimenting with Keras on a time series data application where I created a regression model and then saved it to run on a different Python script.

The time series data that I am dealing with is hourly data, and I am using a saved model in Keras to predict a value for each of hour in the data set. (`data` = CSV file is read into pandas) With a years worth of time series data there is 8760 (hours in a year) predictions and finally I am attempting to sum the values of the predictions at the end.

In the code below I am not showing how the model architecture gets recreated (keras requirement for a saved model) and the code works its just extremely slow. This method seems fine for under a 200 predictions but for a 8760 the code seems to bog down way too much to ever finish.

I don't have any experience with databases but would this be a better method versus storing 8760 keras predictions in a Python list? Thanks for any tips I am still riding the learning curve..

```
#set initial loop params & empty list to store modeled data
row_num = 0
total_estKwh = []


for i, row in data.iterrows():
    params = row.values

    if (params.ndim == 1):
        params = np.array([params])

    estimatedKwh = load_trained_model(weights_path).predict(params)

    print('Analyzing row number:', row_num)

    total_estKwh.append(estimatedKwh)

    row_num += 1


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(total_estKwh)
total = df.sum()
totalStd = np.std(df.values)
totalMean = df.mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are making your life *very* difficult without obvious reason...

For starters, you don't need to *load* your model for every row - this is overkill! You shoud definitely move `load_trained_model(weights_path)` **out** of the `for` loop, with something like

```
model = load_trained_model(weights_path)  # load ONCE
```

and replace the respective line in the loop with

```
estimatedKwh = model.predict(params)
```

Second, it is again not efficient to call the model for prediction row-by-row; it is preferable to first prepare your `params` as an array, and then feed this to the model for getting batch predictions. Forget the `print` statement, too..

All in all, try this:

```
params_array = []

for i, row in data.iterrows():
    params = row.values

    if (params.ndim == 1):
        params = np.array([params])  # is this if really necessary??

    params_array.append(params)

params_array = np.asarray(params_array, dtype=np.float32)
total_estKwh = load_trained_model(weights_path).predict(params_array)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(total_estKwh)
total = df.sum()
totalStd = np.std(df.values)
totalMean = df.mean()
```